# Two divs on top of one div sticking together using twitter-bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, position

I want to achieve a setup like the following:

**[- div -] [-- div --]**

**[------- div --------]**

I want them to stick always together, no matter what the screen size is. What is the best way to achieve this with twitter-bootstrap framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color:red; height:50px"></div>
<div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color:yellow; height:50px"></div>
<div class="col-xs-12" style="background-color:green; height:50px"></div>
</div>
```

use the extra small grid system

[- col-xs-6 -] [- col-xs-6 -]

[------- col-xs-12 --------]

Comment: Some people are so quick in downvoting questions and answers, rather then saying what is not good about it. Especially as a newcomer in the scene like me, it is a little frustrating

Comment: I feel like my answer is right and comes with a practical example

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve without bootstrap as below:

```
[--width:50%--][--width:50%--]
[--width:100%--]
```

May be you have to use other CSS like float:left and clear:both for bottom div

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have bootstrap linked to the page, otherwise you won't be able to make the magic happen. If you really want to learn, I'd recommend checking out w3 for their tutorial.

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/default.asp